# When does $n^{-s}$ stop converging (in terms of $s$)?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I know there must be plenty of material answering this question, but for the life of me I don't know what search terms to use.

So my question is what is the smallest $s$ such that if we take the  sum of the reciprocals of the $s$ powers of all natural numbers we will have convergence? i.e. when does
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}
$$
converge?

Comment: It converges for $s>1$ and diverges for $s \le 1$. You can search for "harmonic series" and "p-series"

Comment: Thanks. If you write this response as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Sandstar, thank you, but I'm okay with leaving it as a comment. It's really a very well known fact and I think it's not very fair to get reputation points for this. I'm just glad I could be of any help

Comment: @Virtuoz This spirit should be more distributed here.

Comment: Or (slightly) more generally, the series converges (even absolutely) for every complex $s \in\Bbb{C}$ such that $\text{Re}(s) > 1$. (In fact, for every $\sigma>1$, the convergence of the series is uniform on $\{s\in \Bbb{C}|\,\,\, \text{Re}(s) \geq \sigma\}$). The proof of this again relies on the "p-series" mentioned above.